# Animate Google marker movement from dynamic coordinates in an array

Tags: ios, swift

I want animate Google marker movement from dynamic coordinates in an array. But marker is moving in a straight line.

My code:

```
for coord in self.lstCoordinate{
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(2.1) 
    self.Marker.position = coord
    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. hope help full for others..

var index = 0

```
func moveMarker(){
    var count: Double = Double(self.lstCoordinate.count)
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(20.0/count)
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock
        {
            if self.index == 0{
                self.lstCoordinate.removeAll()
                return;
            }
            else{
                self.moveMarker()
            }                              

    }

    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn
    self.originMarker.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
    self.Marker.position = lstCoordinate[index]
    CATransaction.commit()

    index = index < lstCoordinate.count - 1 ? index + 1 : 0

}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this solution. Can you let me know what these lines do: `let transition = CATransition()
    transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn
    self.originMarker.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: kCATransition)`

Comment: kCATransitionFade: The layer’s content will fade out when it becomes visible or invisible.
kCATransitionMoveIn: The layer’s content slides over the existing content. Simple transition.subtype subtypes are used with this type.                                 to move marker from old position to new position, i have selected transition type as kCATransitionMoveIn